# select com base em 2 tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho 2 tabelas com a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_campeonato` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `img` text NOT NULL,
  `jogos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vitoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `empate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `derrota` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Gols Pro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Gols Sofridos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `saldo de gol` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pontos` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tb_campeonato` (`id`, `time`, `img`, `jogos`, `vitoria`, `empate`, `derrota`, `Gols Pro`, `Gols Sofridos`, `saldo de gol`, `pontos`) VALUES
(1, 'time1', 'engfoa.png', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(2, 'time2', 'vila.img', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(4, 'time3', 'uss.img', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(3, 'time4', 'medfoa.img', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(5, 'time5', 'edf.img', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(6, 'time6', 'ubm.png', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(7, 'time7', 'ugb.png', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(8, 'time8', 'fer.png', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(9, 'time9', 'aterrado.png', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(10, 'time10', 'odonto.png', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

CREATE TABLE `jogos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time1` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `placar1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `placar2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time2` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `rodada` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `jogos` (`id`, `time1`, `placar1`, `placar2`, `time2`, `rodada`) VALUES
(1, 'time1', 0, 0, 'time6', 1),
(2, 'time2', 34, 32, 'time7', 1),
(3, 'time3', 0, 0, 'time8', 1),
(4, 'time4', 0, 0, 'time9', 1),
(5, 'timr5', 0, 0, 'time10', 1);
```

Ai eu preciso puxar para o php a tabela jogos na ordem certinha mostrando todas as variaveis em ordem (pois são os jogos do campeonato, então puxo mostrando `time1`, `placar1`, `placar2`, `time2`) porem para deixar a tabela de jogos mais bonita estava querendo puxar de acordo com o time, seu escudo (que se encontra na `tb_campeonato` na coluna `img`.
Para isto usei o comando inner join que deu quase certo (`select*from jogos inner join tb_campeonato on tb_campeonato.time=jogos.time1 or jogos.time2=tb_campeonato.time where jogos.rodada=1`).

O problema é que o resultado deste select vem como na foto a seguir: [image: tabela gerada pelo inner join]

Porém não podia repetir as linhas como ocorreu apos o quinto jogo da rodada que seria o ultimo ele mostra todos os 5 jogos novamente para puxar a `img` do `time2`, eu queria uma forma de mostrar todos os dados da tabela jogos e e acrescentar 2 colunas `img1`(`img` referente ao `time1`) e `img2`(`img` referente ao `time2`). qualquer duvida e só falar

Answer (score 0):

faça mais joins, como por exemplo, o primeiro joins para carregar e mostrar os resultados completos e um segundo para pegar o da imagem do time

tente algo deste estilo

```
    SELECT bloco1.id_origem AS pontoA, bloco1.id, bloco1.id_destino AS pontoB, bloco1.hora AS horaAB, bloco2.id_destino AS pontoC, bloco2.hora AS horaBC, bloco2.id 

    FROM TabelaTeste bloco1

    JOIN TabelaTeste bloco2
    ON bloco1.id_destino = bloco2.id_origem AND bloco2.id_destino != bloco1.id_origem

    JOIN TabelaTeste bloco3
    ON bloco1.id_origem = bloco3.id_destino AND bloco2.id_origem != bloco3.id_destino AND bloco2.id_destino = bloco3.id_origem
```

Pode ver o artigo [aqui](https://www.guj.com.br/t/varios-join-em-uma-consulta-sql/282093)

Comment: eu ate entendi, mas nao e isso que to precisando vou editar a pergunta para ser mais claro, até pq acabei de ver que os inserts na tabela estao errados.